# UIDynamics and Device Rotation

Tags: ios7, autolayout, uikit-dynamics, uicollisionbehavior, uidynamicbehavior

If I add any kind of `UIDynamicBehavior` to my views, it completely breaks things when the device is rotated. Here's what it is in portrait (displaying correctly):

[image: Correct Layout]

And here it is in landscape, all broke:[image: Broken layout]

I don't believe it's an autolayout issue because if I remove the calls to add the `UIDynamicBehavior` it works fine with no autolayout problems. No autolayout errors are ever thrown either. Here's the code:

```
@interface SWViewController () {
  UICollisionBehavior *coll;
  UIDynamicAnimator *dynamicAnimator;
}

@implementation SWViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  dynamicAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self setupCollisions]; // commenting this out fixes the layout
}

- (void)setupCollisions {
  NSArray *dynamicViews = @[greenView];
  coll = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:dynamicViews];    
  CGFloat topBound = CGRectGetMinY(greenView.frame);
  [coll addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"top"
                        fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, h1)
                          toPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(greenView.frame), h1)];    
  [dynamicAnimator addBehavior:coll];
}
```

If I override `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` I can see that the top boundary of `greenView` doesn't follow what autolayout says it should (again, removing the call to `setupCollisions` fixes this).

The autolayout boundaries on `greenView` are:

```
height = 200
trailing space to Superview = 0
leading space to Superview = 0
bottom space to Superview = 0
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you are using Collision Behavior here. What does this do without Gravity Behavior? Thanks.

Comment: In this example, I'm not even using a Gravity Behavior. If I switch it out it does the same thing.

Comment: I'd highly recommend watching the WWDC videos on the subject. Sessions 206 and 221 from this year. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ Do create your own questions on SO if you have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I found was to override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and remove the `UIDynamicItems` and then re-add them in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`. This strikes me as rather hacky, and could potentially introduce bugs once I add more complex behaviors.

Comment: I don't really buy this as an answer for this problem, because by reapplying the behavior to the animator, the animation repeats itself, and to do that on each rotation... not elegant.

Comment: I'd love see a better one (please)! Because yes, I had to track the state of things and carefully reapply behaviors so that the animations wouldn't be stuttery and repeat.

Comment: I haven't had to revisit this in a while, but I don't believe iOS 8 provided anything new in terms of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic animator is changing frames of involved views. As a result any animation would be disturbed by a call to `-[UIView setNeedsLayout]` (views would be put to constraint driven positions regardless on dynamic animation state.

My observation is that is you use auto-generated layout constraints the dynamic animator removes them from any view involved in the animation.

If you add your own layout constraints - they persist - but can disturb your animation when view is asked to recalculate layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your auto layout constraints.

I had a very similar problem:

In my case, I have a subview, MyView, which had a set of constraints: V:|-(0)-[MyView], V:[MyView]-(0)-|, H:[MyView:(==300)], and it works good with out UIDynamics. But after adding UIDynamics to MyView, the width changed during rotation, which is very similar to your problem.

I fixed it by adding one more constraint: H:|-(0)-[MyView]